# Android, set text for an EditText on startup

Tags: java, android, user-interface

So I have a simple android app where I take text from a text file (that part is working) and I want to set that text to EditText.setText(). The problem I'm having is that I cannot do this in the onCreate() method because the EditText field and the UI hasn't been created yet(from what it seems).

My question is where would be a good place to do this? Is there a function that is called right after the GUI elements are created?

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
 {
     private final String FILE_NAME = "awayReply";

     private EditText myEditMessage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) 
    {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    String message = readMessage();

    myEditMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);

    if(myEditMessage != null)
    {
        myEditMessage.setText(message, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    }
}
```

XML Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/lbl_message"
    android:inputType="textImeMultiLine" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_update"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/edit_message"
    android:onClick="updateMessage"
    android:text="@string/lbl_update" />
```

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggle_away"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lbl_enable"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lbl_enable"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edit_message"
    android:textOff="Disabled"
    android:textOn="Enabled"
    android:onClick="toggleEnabled" />



 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is there any specific reason you can't do this from xml by settings the text value?

Comment: do it in onStart() or onResume() method

Comment: Thanks i'll give that a shot too. The reason is that the text from the file changes and it cannot be hardcoded.

Comment: Set the value of `myEditText` in the oncreate after setContentView, not in the onStart

Comment: I did that before and it was null.

Comment: Interesting, if there's nothing else wrong, then it shouldn't be null. Aside from what I mentioned in my last comment, I see nothing inherently wrong with your code. So there has to be something else affecting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out my problem. I need to do this work in the PlaceholderFragment where onCreateView is defined. When I call findviewbyid here it dosen't return null.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set your text in a TextView until you inflate your layout with

`setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);`

in the Activity's `OnCreate`

Once that happens you can do:

`EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText)`

Full Example:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // this needs to happen first
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText)
    editText.setText("my text", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE); // <-- needs that second parameter
}
```

Edit: updated for EditText instead of TextView

Comment: I'm actually already doing that. I added the EditText.BufferType.EDITABLE argument but that didn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: use `TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE` not `EditText.BufferType.EDITABLE` .. try that

Comment: The problem I seem to be running into is that findViewById keeps returning null in onCreate and onStart. It makes sense that in onCreate it is null because it hasent been set up yet but onStart should not.

Comment: As long as you're setting it after the setContentView, it shouldn't be, can you post your onCreate and the relevant section of your layout xml? This would help troubleshoot. Add a field to your activity `EditText myEditText;` and then in your onCreate once you assign your edittext to the local variable, then assign it to the fiekd `this.myEditText = editText;` which will give you something to use in OnStart and OnResume